# Better lower bounds than 3n for non-boolean functions?

Tags: circuit-complexity, lower-bounds

Blum's $3n-o(n)$ lower bound is the best known circuit lower bound over the complete basis for an explicit function $f : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$, cf. Jukna's answer to [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/is-there-a-better-than-linear-lower-bound-for-factoring-and-discrete-log) for related results.

What are the best known lower bounds if the range of $f$ is $\{0,1\}^m$?  In particular, do we get anything better for $m = n$, or for $m = 2$?

Comment: isnt this paper studying that? [On the One-Way Function Candidate Proposed by Goldreich](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2012/175/) Cook et al

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the paper [A $5n − o(n)$ Lower Bound on the Circuit Size over $U_2$ of a Linear Boolean Function](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-30870-3_44) by  Kulikov, Melanich, and Mihajlin, when $m=o(n)$ there are no lower bounds known better than $3n - o(n)$. It also outlines a method for obtaining functions for which a $4n - o(n)$ lower bound holds, when $m=n$, based on a result of Lamagne and Savage.

Answer (score 11):

here are new results on this said to be the 1<sup>st</sup> in ~3 decades and some brief commentary

- [A better-than-3n lower bound for the circuit complexity of an explicit function](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2015/166/) / Find, Golovnev, Hirsch, Kulikov

  > We consider Boolean circuits over the full binary basis. We prove a $(3+\frac{1}{86})n−o(n)$ lower bound on the size of such a circuit for an explicitly defined predicate, namely an affine disperser for sublinear dimension. This improves the $3n−o(n)$ bound of Norbert Blum (1984).
- [Better Circuit Lower Bounds for Explicit Functions](https://mittheory.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/not-3n-anymore/) / Ilya Razenshteyn, MIT CSAIL student blog